# Enterprise Library: Redirecting connectionStrings section does not add new ConnectionStrings to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am trying to move connectionStrings to external file using EntLib, but

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` gives me only default ASP.NET database, which is not even in config.

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

I expected to see there two connection string from shared.config. 
What can be the problem, or do I have a wrong understanding this feature?

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>    
        <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>    

    <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="System Configuration Source">
        <sources>
            <add name="System Configuration Source" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.SystemConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add name="Shared" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                filePath="shared.config" />
        </sources>
        <redirectSections>
            <add sourceName="Shared" name="connectionStrings" />
        </redirectSections>
    </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
</configuration>
```

shared.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings> 
        <add name="connStr1" connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="connStr2" connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB2;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` does not know anything about Enterprise Library infrastructure.
By default, sections cannot be redirected with Enterprise Library's ConfigurationSource.

You should use `configSource` attribute, which is feature of .NET Framework, not Enterprise Library.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="sharedConnectionStrings.config" />
</configuration>
```

sharedConnectionStrings.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionsStrings>
    <add name="connStr1"
         connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="connStr2"
         connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB2;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionsStrings>
```

**Update:** If you want to use Enterprise Library features, don't use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` directly. Instead, use Enterprise Library features to create database connections like:

```
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(“Tom’s Connection”);
```

Then you can use Enterprise Library's configuration sources.

I found this [link with example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2006/04/02/external-configuration-files-in-enterprise-library-for-net-framework-2-0/) useful.

Comment: When I saw redirecting connection strings in their configuration tool I thought it supports default section redirecting. Sad, I almost got existed :) Default redirecting mechanism does not allow those cool features of inheriting and merging configs